# Logic app tracked properties are not getting logged in log analytic workspace

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Tracked properties are not getting logged in log analytic workspace. I have configured the required settings in diagnostic settings section of logic app.

Below is logic app code:

```
{
           "definition": {
               "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
               "actions": {
                   "Initialize_variable": {
                       "inputs": {
                           "variables": [
                               {
                                   "name": "test",
                                   "type": "string",
                                   "value": "@triggerBody()?['uid']"
                               }
                           ]
                       },
                       "runAfter": {},
                       "type": "InitializeVariable"
                   },
                   "Response": {
                       "inputs": {
                           "body": "@variables('test')",
                           "statusCode": 200
                       },
                       "kind": "Http",
                       "runAfter": {
                           "Initialize_variable": [
                               "Succeeded"
                           ]
                       },
                       "trackedProperties": {
                           "OutputBlobName": "@triggerBody()?['uid']"
                       },
                       "type": "Response"
                   }
               },
               "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
               "outputs": {},
               "parameters": {},
               "triggers": {
                   "manual": {
                       "inputs": {
                           "schema": {
                               "properties": {
                                   "uid": {
                                       "type": "string"
                                   }
                               },
                               "type": "object"
                           }
                       },
                       "kind": "Http",
                       "type": "Request"
                   }
               }
           },
           "parameters": {}
       }
```

Is there any configuration at workspace level that I ma missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to modify your code a bit. I am sharing an example which might help:

Image 1:

[image]

changing this ( Image 1) to the this (Image 2) did the trick :

Image 2:

[image]

Reference : https://www.connected-pawns.com/2018/06/19/cant-see-tracked-properties-logic-app/

Also you can check : https://peterrombouts.nl/2019/04/01/logicapps-monitoring-with-log-analytics/

Comment: I think the issue is with initialization.  Even when I hard code value in json for tracked properties , it is not getting logged.

Comment: Did you try the "For-each" ?

Comment: Yes, it was throwing track properties evaluation error.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but since you've already got the property you want to track stored in a variable, you can attach tracked properties to that action:

```json
"Initialize_variable": {
  "inputs": { 
    "variables": [
        {"name": "test",
         "type": "string", 
         "value": "@triggerBody()?['uid']" }
      ] },
  "runAfter": {},
  "type": "InitializeVariable", 
  "trackedProperties": {
    "OutputBlobName": "@action().inputs.variables[0].value" 
   }
}
```